# Electronics Engineer or Electronical Engineer

Tags: phrase-usage

Which one is the correct phrase for an engineer whose study field is electronics?

I think, "electronics engineer" is more correct, but sometimes I hear "electronical engineer". The phrase "electronical engineer" seems to me that there is an engineer made of some electronic components.

Comment: A quick Google search or dictionary check would answer this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never seen "Electronical Engineer". But I have seen "Electrical Engineer".

Electrical Engineering is a general term used for all study of electricity, including high-voltage power distribution.

Electronics Engineering is the study of integrated circuits, microprocessors, etc.

Thus, Electronics Engineering is a subset of Electrical Engineering.

Wikipedia has articles about both that might help clear it up:

[Electronic Engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_engineering)

[Electrical Engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_engineering)

Comment: Although I know the word "Electronics" exists and is a perfect fit for this case, I feel more comfortable with the Wikipedia naming, "Electronic Engineering". Also, we can see it is way more used in literature if we throw it in Ngram (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Electronic+Engineering%2C+Electronics+Engineering&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3). So my choice would be Electronic Engineering.

Answer (score 1):

According to the dictionary I usually consult (*Webster's Third New International Dictionary, Unabridged*), "electronical" is not a recognized English word. "Electronics engineer" is in common use. There is also "electrical engineer", although that's not exactly the same thing.